# Will Crashlytics Track User Crashes if it is Complaining About my Missing dSYMs

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Will Crashlytics Track User Crashes if it is Complaining About my Missing dSYMs?

I believe my issue is that "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)" for XCODE 10 might not know where to look since I have a dev and prod info.plist file, but Firebase Crashlytics website doesn't say much about this.

Comment: But wont the missing dSYMs be on the user's devices? How would I get them?

Comment: No, the dSYMs are not on the user’s devices. You’ll want to upload them yourself (or, if you’re using a CI tool, there’s often a process for automating the upload of this to Crashlytics).

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t upload the dSYMs, it will captures the crashes, but it doesn’t include them in the standard reporting. But you can retroactively upload the missing dSYMs and the crash reports will suddenly become visible/usable.

For previous releases, you might check https://appstoreconnect.apple.com, as there’s a link to download the dSYMs there, which you can then upload to Crashlytics. I’d suggest referring to the Crashlytics document titled [Get deobfuscated crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports) for the process of making sure you get these dSYMs uploaded in the future.

---

Also see [TN2151: Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) for broader discussion of dSYMs. Also see WWDC 2018 video [Understanding Crashes and Crash Logs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414/).